# How to fix I/O error when running image that's been copied

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, vmdk

I'm running XP pro on VMware - it mounts and runs just fine.

However, if I power down the VM and try to copy it, or even if I try to do a simple Mac Backup (using Carbon Copy Cloner), I get an i/o error at one very specific VMDK file.

Here's a sample of the error - this from CCC:

> 12/20 22:49:30 Detected input/output error
>   12/20 22:49:33 rsync: read errors mapping "/Users/blahblah/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/WindowsXP-Professional150G.vmwarevm/WindowsXP-Professional150G-000001-s065.vmdk": Input/output error (5)

How can I regain my ability to do backups of my Mac without this I/O error?

Comment: Note:  I can't find the file named ...000001-s065.vmdk in Finder, even when I use Show/HideFiles to show the system files.

Comment: FWIW, Disk Utility says "appears to be Ok" (finds no errors).  I know, Disk Utility doesn't look for bad blocks.

Comment: More info FWIW - Disk Identifier :  disk0s2
 Mount Point :  /
 System Name :  Mac OS X
 System Version :  10.6.5
 System Build :  10H574
 File System :  Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
 Connection Bus :  SATA

Comment: I was able to see the file in the folder contents list using Firefox.  However when I clicked on the file (download) it said, "cannot read".  So I can't copy it to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Input / Output errors are almost always a problem with the hardware.
Generally, it means a corrupt sector on the hard disk, but could also be RAM, or the Logic Board.
The best thing you can do is backup what you still can and replace the hard disk.
Use DiskWarrior or TechTools to do a Surface Scan to verify the hard disk.

Disclaimer: I'm a VMware employee who works on Fusion.

Comment: What do you mean by „logic board”?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation link that CCC directs you to in regards to this error message:

[What are "Input/output" errors, and how can I resolve them?](http://help.bombich.com/faqs/troubleshooting/input-output)

If you're still having trouble, drop us a line at help.bombich.com